# i'm developing a phonegap application but it cannot connect the database i attached the following program?

Tags: javascript, cordova

**  i'm developing a phonegap application  but it cannot connect the database i attached the following program? my code is below:**

```
function onDeviceReady() {

 var mobno = document.getElementById("mobno").value;
 var cust = document.getElementById("cust").value;
 db = window.openDatabase("RegistrationDB", "1.0", "Registration", 200000);
 if (dbCreated)
 else
  db.transaction(populateDB, transaction_error, populateDB_success);
}

function populateDB(tx) {
 tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Registration');
 var sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Registration ( "
   + "mobno INTEGER(50), " + "custname VARCHAR(50))"; 
 tx.executeSql(sql);
 var mobno = document.getElementById("mobno").value;
 var cust =  document.getElementById("cust").value;
 tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO Registration (mobno,custname) VALUES ('"+ mobno +"','"+ cust +"')");

}

function transaction_error(tx, error) {
 alert("Database Error: " + error);
}

function populateDB_success() {
 dbCreated = true;

 // where you want to move
 alert("Successfully inserted");
  window.location="file:///android_asset/www/login.html";
}
```

Comment: I'm not a phonegap expert, but you should probably tell us what the error is that you get when you try to attach to the database, and how you set up the database in the first place (if at all). Your `if (dbCreated) else` without anything in the positive case looks suspicious too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to use the Cordova SqlLite plugin you have to install it:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin
```

next you can create the db in device ready:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
  var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Demo", -1);

  db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table (id integer primary key, data text, data_num integer)');

    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO test_table (data, data_num) VALUES (?,?)", ["test", 100], function(tx, res) {
      console.log("insertId: " + res.insertId + " -- probably 1");
      console.log("rowsAffected: " + res.rowsAffected + " -- should be 1");

      tx.executeSql("select count(id) as cnt from test_table;", [], function(tx, res) {
        console.log("res.rows.length: " + res.rows.length + " -- should be 1");
        console.log("res.rows.item(0).cnt: " + res.rows.item(0).cnt + " -- should be 1");
      });

    }, function(e) {
      console.log("ERROR: " + e.message);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: You may well be right, but there's nothing about plugins in [their edge documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_storage_storage.opendatabase.md.html) and they still just use `window.openDatabase` not `window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase`.